# Auto Approve Review Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, review

I am developing one website which has many products and customers. So many customers are posting reviews.

I have to auto approve this review, but not getting how to achieve this.

Please give me some hints or suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

**Observer way:**

In custom module (in my case `Giss\ReviewAutoApprove\`).

Create event `etc\frontend\events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="review_save_before">
        <observer name="review_auto_approve" instance="Giss\ReviewAutoApprove\Observer\ReviewSaveBeforeObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Create observer `Observer\ReviewSaveBeforeObserver.php`

```
<?php

namespace Giss\ReviewAutoApprove\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Review\Model\Review;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ReviewSaveBeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog */
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $loggerInterface
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
    }

    /**
     * This is the method that fires when the event runs.
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->logger->addDebug('Executed Review Save After Observer');

        /** @var Review $review */
        $review = $observer->getDataByKey('object');
        $review->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_APPROVED);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to enable module, clear:cache...

Answer (score 1):

You can use event observer in your custom module to do this.

1. Observe the event `review_save_before`
2. Modify the model by updating the `status` to `STATUS_APPROVED`

Comment: I have checked for this event but i think it's not available in magento 2.

Comment: This event is not directly triggered.  It is triggered by the code $this->_eventManager->dispatch($this->_eventPrefix . '_save_before', $this->_getEventData()); in file vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php

Comment: How can I do this by event and observer? I have created event.xml file and getting event review_save_before.

Comment: Go through http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

Comment: Yes but I am not understanding how to get review data in the observer and how to modify status. I have used this but not getting data 
$data = $observer->getEvent()->getReview();

Answer (score 0):

You could override `\Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post` in your own module and change:

```
->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
```

to:

```
->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
```

You can do this by copying the class to your own module: `\Local\Review\Controller\Product\Post`

And create a preferencer in your `di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post" type="Local\Review\Controller\Product\Post" />  
</config>
```

Now run: 
`bin/magento cache:flush` and `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: How can I do this by event and observer? I have created event.xml file and getting event review_save_before.

Comment: There is no `review_save_before` event, but check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Product review status set from this controller : `vendor/magento/module-review/Controller/Product/Post.php`

You have to orverride controller method by plugin and just change the line

```
->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
```

with

```
->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
```

Comment: How can I do this by event and observer? I have created event.xml file and getting event review_save_before.

Comment: You should use plugin for override the controller method.

Comment: But I don't have to override any Magento file.

Comment: Yes but you can override controller method